# Неправильное слияние разных по длине DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, join

При попытки слияния двух DataFrame получается неправильно заполненный `df3`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('140101_200524.csv')
df1.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'X+100']

df1['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'].astype(str))

del df1['Date'] 
df1['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Data'], format='%Y-%m-%d') \
                 .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').str.lstrip("0")

df2 = pd.read_csv('l_d.csv')
df2.columns = ['Date', 'Commo']

df2['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'].astype(str))

del df2['Date'] 
df2['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Data'], format='%Y-%m-%d') \
                 .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').str.lstrip("0")

df3 = df2.merge(df1, on="Data")
df3
```

Итог, который зависит от воли случая и длинны первого `df`. По сути получается слияние как попало.

Нужно получить `df1` во столько же строк как он и был и к нему добавить `df2`, который меньше значительно.

[Файлы](http://file.sampo.ru/t5dvdf/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужно получить df1 во столько же строк как он и был и к нему добавить
>   df2 который меньше значительно.

В реляционной алгебре это называется [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Left_outer_join_(%E2%9F%95)) - это когда мы берем все записи из первой (левой) таблицы и те записи из правой таблицы, для которых нашлись совпадения по ключу.

В Pandas для этого используют параметр `how`, который по умолчанию равен `inner`, что эквивалентно `INNER JOIN`.

---

В вашем случае:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on="Data", how="left")
```

или:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on="Data", how="right")
```

Comment: @Николай, не понимаю...

Comment: @Николай, можно: `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on="Data", how="left")` ;)